# s3cmd failed after try to create a testbucket on ceph-cluster

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ceph, s3cmd

Hello I am trying to create a testbucket on a Ceph Raspberry Pi cluster(local) and I get the following error message:

OS:Debian Jessie
Ceph: v12.2.12 Luminous
s3cmd:2.0.2

```
[ceph_deploy.rgw][INFO  ] The Ceph Object Gateway (RGW) is now running on host admin and default port 7480

 ./s3cmd --debug mb s3://testbucket
```

Debug Message:

```
DEBUG: Unicodising 'mb' using UTF-8
DEBUG: Unicodising 's3://testbucket' using UTF-8
DEBUG: Command: mb
DEBUG: CreateRequest: resource[uri]=/
DEBUG: Using signature v2
DEBUG: SignHeaders: u'PUT\n\n\n\nx-amz-date:Wed, 15 Jan 2020 02:28:25 +0000\n/testbucket/'
DEBUG: Processing request, please wait...
DEBUG: get_hostname(testbucket): 192.168.178.50:7480
DEBUG: ConnMan.get(): creating new connection: http://192.168.178.50:7480
DEBUG: non-proxied HTTPConnection(192.168.178.50, 7480)
DEBUG: Response:


DEBUG: Unicodising './s3cmd' using UTF-8
DEBUG: Unicodising '--debug' using UTF-8
DEBUG: Unicodising 'mb' using UTF-8
DEBUG: Unicodising 's3://testbucket' using UTF-8
Invoked as: ./s3cmd --debug mb s3://testbucket
Problem: error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
S3cmd:   2.0.2
python:   2.7.17 (default, Oct 19 2019, 23:36:22)
[GCC 9.2.1 20190909]
environment LANG=en_GB.UTF-8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./s3cmd", line 3092, in <module>
    rc = main()
  File "./s3cmd", line 3001, in main
    rc = cmd_func(args)
  File "./s3cmd", line 237, in cmd_bucket_create
    response = s3.bucket_create(uri.bucket(), cfg.bucket_location)
  File "/home/cephuser/s3cmd-2.0.2/S3/S3.py", line 398, in bucket_create
    response = self.send_request(request)
  File "/home/cephuser/s3cmd-2.0.2/S3/S3.py", line 1258, in send_request
    conn = ConnMan.get(self.get_hostname(resource['bucket']))
  File "/home/cephuser/s3cmd-2.0.2/S3/ConnMan.py", line 253, in get
    conn.c.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 831, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Does anyone know about the error ?

Comment: I think I have to solve this problem first:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751876/ceph-rgw-service-stop-automatically-after-installation

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
[Ceph-rgw Service stop automatically after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751876/ceph-rgw-service-stop-automatically-after-installation/59760429#59760429)

After my gateway was permanently available I could create a testbucket with s3cmd