# Ceph-rgw Service stop automatically after installation

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, ceph

in my local cluster (4 Raspberry PIs) i try to configure a rgw gateway. Unfortunately the services disappears automatically after 2 minutes.

```
[ceph_deploy.rgw][INFO  ] The Ceph Object Gateway (RGW) is now running on host OSD1 and default port 7480


cephuser@admin:~/mycluster $ ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     745d44c2-86dd-4b2f-9c9c-ab50160ea353
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            too few PGs per OSD (24 < min 30)

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum admin
    mgr: admin(active)
    osd: 4 osds: 4 up, 4 in
    rgw: 1 daemon active

  data:
    pools:   4 pools, 32 pgs
    objects: 80 objects, 1.09KiB
    usage:   4.01GiB used, 93.6GiB / 97.6GiB avail
    pgs:     32 active+clean

  io:
    client:   5.83KiB/s rd, 0B/s wr, 7op/s rd, 1op/s wr
```

After one minute the service(rgw: 1 daemon active) is no longer visible:

```
cephuser@admin:~/mycluster $ ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     745d44c2-86dd-4b2f-9c9c-ab50160ea353
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            too few PGs per OSD (24 < min 30)

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum admin
    mgr: admin(active)
    osd: 4 osds: 4 up, 4 in

  data:
    pools:   4 pools, 32 pgs
    objects: 80 objects, 1.09KiB
    usage:   4.01GiB used, 93.6GiB / 97.6GiB avail
    pgs:     32 active+clean
```

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
On the gateway node, open the Ceph configuration file in the /etc/ceph/ directory.

Find an RGW client section similar to the example:

```
[client.rgw.gateway-node1]
host = gateway-node1
keyring = /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.gateway-node1/keyring
log file = /var/log/ceph/ceph-rgw-gateway-node1.log
rgw frontends = civetweb port=192.168.178.50:8080 num_threads=100
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ceph_storage/3/html-single/object_gateway_guide_for_red_hat_enterprise_linux/index